# symfony2 sonataUserBundle define new role and add to user

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata

I'm using Symfony2 with sonataAdminBundle, sonataUserBundle and FOSUserBundle. I would like to create a new role e.g. ROLE_TEST. When I go to edit a user in the admin CRUD interface, I would like that role to appear in the 'roles' section so I can add it to the user.

Where do I define the role so it appears in that list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add these roles under the ROLE_ADMIN role (or to whatever role the logged in admin user is member of) in the role hierarchy.

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_TEST]
```

[see here the code](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/blob/master/Form/Type/SecurityRolesType.php#L60)